# Multiple associations in Relative Risk and Odds Ratio

Tags: r, epidemiology, association-measure

I am a frequent user of the package (epiR), especially in Relative Risk and Odds Ratio.

Generally, I use several covariates to make the associations (RR or OR), for example: outcome (death) versus exposure (Age, Gender, Length of Hospitalization, ICU, etc.). With that, I have to generate the same process several times, changing only the exposures.

I would like to know if the package allows to perform these associations in a unique way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by the word "unique"?